# Markable ListView with changing Actionbar Actions

Tags: java, android, listview, select, android-actionbar

Im trying to find out how I can mark things in ListViews with a longClick. After I selected one item ,the Actionbar should change with diffrent options (buttons like delete, add , copy etc) which Im able to execute.I really didnt know how I can find these examples because Its a kind unique I guess. I founded threads where I can Mark an Item which gets a diffrent color and nothing else. How can I achieve this ?

**Before selecting :**
[image: Before selecting]

**After long click :**
[image: After a long Click on a Item]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add an onLongClickListener in your `ListView` or `RecyclerView` but for each list_item you will have to specify a checkbox that will become visible only when you longClick the `ListView`.

Then if you do not want to mess up the actionBar with new menu items you can create a context menu that will do your job.

You can use a [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) or you can also use a CardView with a contexual menu as shown in the picture [here](http://frogermcs.github.io/InstaMaterial-concept-part-4-feed-context-menu/).

Comment: Contextual Menu was the Keyword ! Thanks